# rpm installation failed with errors

Tags: linux

I was trying to install  RDO repositories in my centos 7 but I am getting the following errors

```
# yum install -y https://rdoproject.org/repos/rdo-release.rpm
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, langpacks
rdo-release.rpm                                                                                                                                                          | 5.1 kB  00:00:00     
Examining /var/tmp/yum-root-lLOS4K/rdo-release.rpm: rdo-release-liberty-2.noarch
/var/tmp/yum-root-lLOS4K/rdo-release.rpm: does not update installed package.
Error: Nothing to do
```

Can somebody help me on this?